# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin generating @Schema annotation for generated request models class fields instead fo @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

Using:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>client-w</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/w/w-swagger.yml</inputSpec>
          <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
          <language>jaxrs-cxf-client</language>
          <apiPackage>com.w.w.swagger.api</apiPackage>
          <modelPackage>com.w.w.swagger.model</modelPackage>
          <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
          <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
          <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
          <skipOverwrite>true</skipOverwrite>
          <configOptions>
            <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
            <java8>true</java8>
          <sourceFolder>swagger</sourceFolder>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

generates...

```
  @Schema(required = true, description = "")
  private CreateAlarmReq createAlarmReq = null;
 /**
   * Get createAlarmReq
   * @return createAlarmReq
  **/
  @JsonProperty("CreateAlarmReq")
  public CreateAlarmReq getCreateAlarmReq() {
    return createAlarmReq;
```

The thing is, if I create & use at the controller a custom model with all request body json properties as @JsonProperty instead of @Schema (I mean the class fields instead of getters), it works. Otherwise, with swagger pluggin generated models, @RequestBody fails to parse json body thworing a 415 Unsupported Media Type.

THIS WORKS (done manually):

```
  @JsonProperty("CreateAlarmReq"))
  private CreateAlarmReq createAlarmReq = null;
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK (generated by swagger-codegen-maven-plugin):

```
  @Schema(required = true, description = "")
  private CreateAlarmReq createAlarmReq = null;

  @JsonProperty("CreateAlarmReq")
  public CreateAlarmReq getCreateAlarmReq() {
    return createAlarmReq;
```

YML (fields changed for privacy):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: ManageBrie
  description: This interface manages creation and modification of Brie
  version: '1.0'
host: api.host.com
basePath: /rest/ManageBrie
schemes:
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic
    description: HTTP Basic Authentication. Works over `HTTP` and `HTTPS`
paths:
  /createBrie:
    post:
      tags:
        - ManageBrie
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
      operationId: createBrieResponseMessage
      summary: This operation creates one or several Brie
      description: ''
      deprecated: false
      parameters:
        - name: createBrie
          in: body
          required: true
          description: ''
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CreateBrieMessage'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CreateBrieResponseMessage'
        '400':
          description: bad request
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/FaultResponseMessage'
        '500':
          description: internal server error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/FaultResponseMessage'
  /updateBrie:
    post:
      tags:
        - ManageBrie
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
      operationId: updateBrieResponseMessage
      summary: This operation update one or several Brie
      description: ''
      deprecated: false
      parameters:
        - name: updateBrie
          in: body
          required: true
          description: ''
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateBrieMessage'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateBrieResponseMessage'
        '400':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/FaultResponseMessage'
        '500':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/FaultResponseMessage'
definitions:
  CreateBrieMessage:
    description: ''
    required:
      - CreateBrieReq
    type: object
    properties:
      CreateBrieReq:
        $ref: '#/definitions/CreateBrieReq'
  CreateBrieResponseMessage:
    description: ''
    required:
      - CreateBrieReq
    type: object
    properties:
      CreateBrieReq:
        $ref: '#/definitions/CreateBrieRes'
  UpdateBrieMessage:
    description: ''
    required:
      - UpdateBrieReq
    type: object
    properties:
      UpdateBrieReq:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateBrieReq'
  UpdateBrieResponseMessage:
    description: ''
    required:
      - UpdateBrieReq
    type: object
    properties:
      UpdateBrieReq:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateBrieRes'
  CreateBrieReq:
    description: ''
    required:
      - technicalCamembert
      - Brie
    type: object
    properties:
      technicalCamembert:
        description: 'technical context'
        $ref: '#/definitions/technicalCamembert'
      Brie:
        description: 'list of Brie to create'
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/BrieCreate'
  CreateBrieRes:
    description: ''
    required:
      - results
    type: object
    properties:
      results:
        description: 'results'
        type: string
  UpdateBrieReq:
    description: ''
    required:
      - technicalCamembert
      - Brie
    type: object
    properties:
      technicalCamembert:
        description: 'technical context'
        $ref: '#/definitions/technicalCamembert'
      Brie:
        description: 'list of Brie to update'
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/BrieUpdate'
  UpdateBrieRes:
    description: ''
    required:
      - results
    type: object
    properties:
      results:
        description: 'results'
        type: string
  technicalCamembert:
    description: 'technical context'
    required:
      - sender
      - recipient
      - flowId
      - flowName
      - flowVersion
      - sendDate
      - BrieCount
    type: object
    properties:
      sender:
        description: 'sender name = USA'
        type: string
      recipient:
        description: 'recipient name = VXZK'
        type: string
      flowId:
        description: 'flowId is used when a flow is sent twice'
        type: string
      flowName:
        description: 'flow name = Création Briees'
        type: string
      flowVersion:
        description: 'flow version = 1.0'
        type: string
      ackFlag:
        description: 'acknowledgement flag'
        type: boolean
      ackMode:
        description: 'acknowledgement send mode (mail, ...)'
        type: string
      sendDate:
        description: 'send date, format DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:SS'
        type: string
      BrieCount:
        description: 'number of Brie'
        type: string
  BrieCreate:
    description: 'Brie creation'
    required:
      - idBrie
      - dateBrie
      - sourceBrie
      - typeBrie
      - typeBastille
      - croissantTurcs
      - regionalDirectionPapirus
      - etatSoleil
      - foiegras
      - Turc
      - login
      - seR
    type: object
    properties:
      idBrie:
        description: 'unique identifier for the Brie'
        type: string
      dateBrie:
        description: "Brie's detection date (precision : 15min)"
        type: string
      sourceBrie:
        description: "Brie's source (PPP disconnection or DHCP session)"
        type: string
      typeBrie:
        description: "Brie's type (network failure or deterioration)"
        type: string
      idGroupBrie:
        description: "Brie's USA group id"
        type: string
      typeBastille:
        description: "Brie's USA group id"
        type: string
      croissantTurcs:
        description: 'main impacting Turc'
        type: string
      regionalDirectionPapirus:
        description: "impacting Turc's regional direction Papirus"
        type: string
      center:
        description: "impacting Turc's center Papirus"
        type: string
      reign:
        description: 'name of the reign impacted'
        type: string
      etatSoleil:
        description: 'etatSoleil Papirus of the impacted reign'
        type: string
      reignInseePapirus:
        description: "impacted reign's insee Papirus"
        type: string
      foiegras:
        description: 'adsf site'
        type: string
      Turc:
        description: 'list of Turcs concerned by the Brie'
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/TurcCreate'
      login:
        description: 'list of customers ND having RossetaPiramid = 1'
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Login'
      seR:
        description: "Brie's sequential number"
        type: string
  TurcCreate:
    description: 'Turc creation'
    required:
      - name
      - type
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        description: 'Turc name'
        type: string
      type:
        description: 'Turc type (Fripouille, ...)'
        type: string
      impacting:
        description: 'whether the Turc is impacting'
        type: boolean
      tourLouvre:
        description: 'whether the Turc is secondary impacting'
        type: boolean
      letempsdesfleurs:
        description: 'number of customers with issue at the time of the Brie'
        type: string
      louismoins16:
        description: 'number of customers connected to the Turc at the time of the Brie'
        type: string
      daleatucuerpoalegriamacarena:
        description: 'number of customers connected to the Turc during the last 7 days'
        type: string
  Login:
    description: 'login'
    required:
      - loginTest
    type: object
    properties:
      loginTest:
        description: 'customer sadf for a customer with RossetaPiramid=1'
        type: string
  BrieUpdate:
    description: 'Brie update'
    required:
      - idBrie
      - dateUpdateBrie
      - Turc
      - seR
    type: object
    properties:
      idBrie:
        description: 'unique identifier for the Brie'
        type: string
      dateUpdateBrie:
        description: "Brie's update date (precision : 15min)"
        type: string
      typeBrie:
        description: "Brie's type (network failure or deterioration)"
        type: string
      idGroupBrie:
        description: "Brie's USA group id"
        type: string
      statusClosed:
        description: "closing type (administrative or normal)"
        type: string
      idBrieMaster:
        description: "substituting id for a closed Brie"
        type: string
      Turc:
        description: 'list of Turcs concerned by the Brie'
        type: array
        minItems: 1
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/TurcUpdate'
      seR:
        description: "Brie's sequential number"
        type: string
  TurcUpdate:
    description: 'Turc update'
    required:
      - name
      - type
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        description: 'Turc name'
        type: string
      type:
        description: 'Turc type (Fripouille, ...)'
        type: string
      impacting:
        description: 'impacting Turc indicator'
        type: boolean
      tourLouvre:
        description: 'impacting secondary Turc indicator'
        type: boolean
      letempsdesfleurs:
        description: 'number of customers with issue at the time of the Brie'
        type: string
      louismoins16:
        description: 'number of customers connected to the Turc at the time of the Brie'
        type: string
      daleatucuerpoalegriamacarena:
        description: 'number of customers connected to the Turc during the last 7 days'
        type: string
      restore:
        description: "Turc's State (f -> not restore t-> restore)"
        type: string
      dateRestore:
        description: "Turc's restore date (precision : 15min)"
        type: string
  FaultResponseMessage:
    description: 'fault response message'
    required:
      - fault
    type: object
    properties:
      fault:
        description: 'fault'
        type: array
        minItems: 0
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Fault'
  Fault:
    description: 'fault'
    required:
      - idBrie
      - faultLabel
    type: object
    properties:
      idBrie:
        description: 'unique identifier for the Brie'
        type: string
      faultLabel:
        description: 'litteral description of the fault name'
        type: string
```

I thought it was 'swagger: 2.0' in .yml clashing with io.swagger.codegen.v3 maven plugin but after converting to openapi3 at https://editor.swagger.io/ the same result happened:

```
HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type
```

What is going on? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share w-swagger.yml?